# mysql server won't start after running fsck

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, fsck

I had a power outage after which my server didn't start anymore. I ended up running fsck and check the drive using smartctl afterwards. The overall health test passed and everything seems to work except mysql.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Here are some logs, especially the error.log shows some "Tablespace ... was not found" and "Cannot open datafile .." errors. The database files in /var/lib/mysql are still there.

I also tried to run "innodb_force_recovery" with all 6 values in /etc/mysql/my.cnf with no result.

> systemctl status mysql.service

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Di 2019-06-11 11:31:52 CEST; 15s ago
  Process: 8110 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 8101 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8110 (code=exited, status=2);         : 8111 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─8111 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─8172 sleep 1

Jun 11 11:31:52 serber systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jun 11 11:31:53 serber systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

> journalctl -xe

```
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber audit[8218]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/8218/status" pid=8218 comm="mys
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber audit[8218]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=8218 c
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber audit[8218]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/8218/status" pid=8218 comm="mys
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1560245543.341:7230): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1560245543.341:7231): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1560245543.341:7232): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber audit[8243]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/8218/task/8243/mem" pid=8243 co
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1560245543.861:7233): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
Jun 11 11:32:23 serber systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 11 11:32:53 serber systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 11 11:32:53 serber systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 11 11:32:53 serber systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 11 11:32:53 serber systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 11 11:32:53 serber systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Jun 11 11:32:53 serber systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
```

> /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2019-06-11T09:40:09.274147Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 55302581654
2019-06-11T09:40:09.274268Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: At LSN: 55302581435: unable to open file ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd for tablespace 506
2019-06-11T09:40:09.274277Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-06-11T09:40:09.274280Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.274748Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace 506 was not found at './mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd', but there were no modificati      ons either.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.441985Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442009Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442014Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does       not create them.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442019Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './mysql/help_category.ibd' OS error: 71
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442023Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442026Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442030Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does       not create them.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442042Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `mysql/help_category`. Please refer to http://dev.      mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442048Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace `mysql/help_category` because it could not be opened.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442111Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442116Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442120Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does       not create them.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442123Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd' OS error: 71
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442126Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442129Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442132Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does       not create them.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442136Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `mysql/innodb_index_stats`. Please refer to http:/      /dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.442140Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace `mysql/innodb_index_stats` because it could not be opened.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.445987Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-06-11T09:40:09.445996Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-06-11T09:40:09.446026Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-06-11T09:40:09.634990Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.635646Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.635654Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.635970Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636594Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `mysql`.`innodb_index_stats` in the cache. Attempting to       load the tablespace with space id 506
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636618Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636625Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636650Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd' OS error: 71
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636656Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636659Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2019-06-11T09:40:09.636664Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for `mysql/innodb_index_stats`. Please refer to http:/      /dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
09:40:09 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76388 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f5aec000900
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f5af1ffaca0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xe9510b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x489)[0x78ad29]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f5b11cec390]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z28fil_space_is_being_truncatedm+0xc0)[0x1122b80]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14row_purge_stepP9que_thr_t+0x286)[0xfd6026]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15que_run_threadsP9que_thr_t+0xa69)[0xf832f9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z9trx_purgemmb+0xab5)[0x1037b15]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_purge_coordinator_thread+0x445)[0x100c9e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f5b11ce26ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f5b1117741d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem like this:
(The following steps describe activities that irrevocably change the data and can lead to data loss.)

1. Stop MySQL if necessary
2. Backup InnoDB-Files (/var/lib/mysql/ib*)
3. Add these lines to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

   > [mysqld]
   >   innodb_force_recovery = 4
4. Start MySQL in safe mode:

   > sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables
5. Backup all databases (`mysqldump -A > dump.sql`) or single databases (`mysqldump database > database.sql`)
6. Drop the tables (`drop database mydatabase;`)
7. Stop MySQL
8. Delete the InnoDB-Files (/var/lib/mysql/ib*)
9. Remove `innodb_force_recovery=4` from the config
10. Start MySQL like normal (`sudo service mysql start`). The new ib*-files are now generated.
11. Restore your databases

    > mysql < dump.sql

    for the full backup or

    > create database mydatabase;
    >   mysql mydatabase < mydatabase.sql